# WP7 Notifications (non-push) think Alarm clock

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to create a timer that will send out an alarm (messagebox or some other UI that the user has to interact with).  The alarm is long running (like and alarm clock).  I have looked for a solution and keep getting info on push notifications, but I think having a webservice track and alert 1000 users alarms clocks would be the wrong way to go, not to mention that the user would have to have network connections.  I don't know about you, but my HD7 didn't have a connection in WV this past weekend (or any weekend I would guess).

I read several posts here and still nothing.  I built the same app on Android and iPhone fairly quickly, but on my "home" platform of c# I'm stumped.

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible using Background tasks in WP7.5 Mango API. Please read upon this here - http://www.abhishekshukla.com/development/windows-phone-7-mango-background/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a sccenario which is currently supported. You cannot write code which runs in the background.

The phones come with very good alarm clock support anyway.

The alternative to running in the background is to have a remote service send a notification to the device at the desired time. If you want something more you'll have to wait for a future verison of the platform.

Comment: Its not a wake up alarm, its part of the event system in a health care app.  The user has to interact with it.  Well, this would explain why I couldn't find anything on it.  Thanks Matt.

Comment: Just a note that I read somewhere in the T&C's for Push notifications that they are not to be used for mission critical / life-or-death situations, since Microsoft can't technically guarantee 100% uptime, so you may or may not be able to use push notifications for your healthcare app depending on what the scope of the application is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation.  Currently it looks like toast push notifications are the only option.  For something like an alarm clock, that's not so great.  No guarantee of delivery and they'll disappear from view after being ignored.

Depending on how far out the alarm needs to be triggered, I'm considering manually subscribing to a "special" calendar (in the cloud!) and then programmatically setting appointments (with reminders, of course).  Not sure how soon the calendar changes would sync back to the phone after a change.  You'd still need a network connection at some point to make the change and receive the calendar update.  Just a theory.  Haven't tried it yet.

Sure would be nice if there was a way to schedule some of that locally in a future API release.

Comment: Yea, I am fairly put off by it.  In IOS you can use something like: (Mono Touch example)
  
 localNotification.FireDate = (NSDate)fireDate;
 UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(localNotification);

and in Android SDK something like:

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime, sender);

Both allow you to attach to the system service and rehydrate your app after the call.  I get no multitasking, but IOS allows this back in 3.x